# How to click the element inside the ::before and ::after

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to click the second

element  inside the . I tried with the Iterator, but it is not working. Please suggest the way to click the element which is surrounded by ::before and ::after

**Here is my HTML code of my wep page.**

```
<section class="SHops" data-shop-code="453">
        <div class="heading-underlined centered">
            <h3>Cake Shop<span class="underline"></span></h3>
        </div>
<ul class="brand-list cf equal-height cakes">
    ::before
                <li style="height: 223.316px;">
                    ...
                </li>
                <li style="height: 223.316px;">
                    ...
                </li>
                <li style="height: 223.316px;">
                    ...
                </li>
    ::after
        </ul>enter code here
 </section>
```

**Here is my Selenium-Java Test automation code:**

```
@FindBy(css = "article.airport-info > section:nth-child(2)")
private WebElement cakeShopTwo;

public void selectYourCake(String cake) {
    Iterator<WebElement> itr = cakeShopTwo.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        WebElement element = itr.next();
        String loungeName = itr.next().getText();
        if (loungeName == lounge) {
            element.click();
        }
    }
}
```

I got the below error message after running the test automation script.

*java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:364)*

Comment: There is no element with css `article.airport-info` in the DOM which you have posted.Please post it in right way which element you need to select with your xpath. Usually :Before,:After will have content or an `img` url so post it along with screenshot of your rendered web page if you need to select this pseudo elements

Comment: @Thiru mate these is some issue with your css locator you have provided inside FindBy. As i can see in DOM there is nothing called "article.airport-info". Also as per your case you are expecting only one web-element not the list, then why you are trying to iterate through it ? Correct your locator and then simply you can click it using cakeShopTwo.click()

Comment: Here is the HTML code for article.airport-info         
<article class="airport-info">
    <section class="xxxxx">
            <ul class="xxxxx">
                    <li style="height: 223.316px;">
                        ...
                    </li>
                    <li style="height: 223.316px;">
                        ...
                    </li>
                    <li style="height: 223.316px;">
                        ...
                    </li>
               </ul>

Comment: Which element you want to select?

Comment: Second <li>... </li>